# How do I convert a python string to ucs2 hex?

Tags: python, encoding

I've been searching for this one and couldn't find it, although it seems simple. I need to send in a ucs2 hex string in the url, and I don't know how to convert a python string to be ucs2 hex. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> 'åéîøü'.encode('utf16')
b'\xff\xfe\xe5\x00\xe9\x00\xee\x00\xf8\x00\xfc\x00'
```

(Note that there's a BOM in the beginning. Use the encoding `'utf_16_be'` or `'utf_16_le'` if the endian is fixed.)

If you need hex digits, use [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/binascii.html?highlight=binascii.hexlify#binascii.hexlify).

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('åéîøü'.encode('utf16'))
b'fffee500e900ee00f800fc00'
```

Comment: body = "ואו הצלחתי לשלוח בעברית"
    
    body = binascii.hexlify(smart_unicode(body).encode('utf16'))

Comment: ok, I managed to solve it, thanks. BTW, when you use this you need to switch the order of the hex chars (05d0 comes out d005) and if you mix spaces and latin letters you need to handle them seperately since they occupy only one char instead of two.

Comment: Eventually, the thing that worked with no further adjustments was:
ucs2_body = body.encode("utf_16_be").encode("hex")

Comment: @apple: Note that `.encode('hex')` is no longer available on Python 3.x.

Comment: UCS-2 ≠ UTF-16. The former is fixed-with and only encodes code points ≤ 0xFFFF. The latter can encode those above and you don't need the pigeonhole principle to figure out that if UTF-16 can encode 1 112 064 code points then it will be more than 2 bytes.