# Why is the encoding from Exif tags fail after updating image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, pysimplegui

I have to in to a problem with adding new tags to Exif data for an image.

### The setting

I have created a PySimpleGUI python script for simple image manipulation and worked out all but the last steps.

The script displays an image (jpg, jepg) and a key Exif data.  The script uses a series of checkboxes to 'tag' and image quickly from a selection (list).  I have the array of checkboxes, image updating properly.  So I can decode the Exif data properly, but when I want to update the image I run into problems.

I use Windows 10 with Python3, with Imports from PIL, PySimpleGUI.

The meta data:

- **40094** (Exif ID for the key I want to update)
- **Exif.Image.XPKeywords**
- Byte (variable type)
- Keywords tag used by Windows (encoded in UCS2)

I found some help:  [Encode UCS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279830/how-do-i-convert-a-python-string-to-ucs2-hex)

Using the help from above I can get this:

`Exif: b'O\x00u\x00t\x00d\x00o\x00o\x00r\x00;\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00\x00\x00'`

Converts to `Outdoor;art`

```
<i = 40094>
    img = Image.open(pathname + '\\' + filename)
    exifDataRaw = img._getexif()
        if exifDataRaw.get(i):
            if exifDataRaw[i]:
                print("Exif:", exifDataRaw[i])
                return str(exifDataRaw[i].decode('utf-16'))
```

Good, I can convert that `str` to a list and update the checkboxes.

### Updating the Tags (Keywords)

I add more keywords to the `str`.  Now:`Outdoor;art;box;machine;`

To update the keys I have this function.  Checkboxes selected are True, and unselected are False.
PySimpleGUI as collects **events** and **vales**.  The function scans the values for selected "True".
TaggerList is the master list of tags I use in the script.  When a checkbox is True the loop adds the Tags to the `InsertString`.  Shown above.

```
def PushTags(pathname, filename):
    InsertString = ""
    img = Image.open(pathname + '\\' + filename)
    for Tag in TaggerList[:-1]:
        if values[Tag]:
            InsertString = InsertString + Tag + ";"
            first = False
    #Get whole dataset
    exifDataRaw = img._getexif()
    i = 40094
    # Set new data to Exif
    exifDataRaw[i] = InsertString[:-1].encode('utf-16')  # remove the last ";" and encode
    img.save(pathname + '\\' + filename, exif=exifDataRaw)   #Update image with new values
```

I can use `Image.Exif.__setitem__(i, InsertString[:-1].encode('utf-16'))` to save just the updated keywords.

But the encoding still give an error.

The original: `Exif: b'O\x00u\x00t\x00d\x00o\x00o\x00r\x00;\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00\x00\x00'`

Saved Tags: `b'\xff\xfeu\x00t\x00d\x00o\x00o\x00r\x00;\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00;\x00b\x00o\x00x\x00;\x00m\x00a\x00c\x00h\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00'`

The encoding does not seem to be mutual both ways.  The encoded string adds `'\xff\xfeu` I assume \xfeu is a capital 'O'.

The encoding is wrong and breaks the image.  General image viewers error out the updated image.

If I can fix this I can then finish the script.

Comment: `\xff\xfe` is a byte order mark and an optional part of the encoding.

Comment: I can see if there any notes about optional encoding.  Still, How do I turn it off as the data needs to be byte compatible. I need this as the start: `O\x00u...`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was at issue.
The encoding is a priory to byte order.

To get the format I wanted I needed little endian notation.  In python `utf_16_le` little  and `utf_16_be` for big endian codecs.

`utf_16_le` puts the first 8 bits of the data at the head and then the last 8 bits at the tail.

```
i = 40094
img = Image.open(pathname + '\\' + filename)
exifDataRaw = img._getexif()
    if exifDataRaw.get(i):
        if exifDataRaw[i]:
            print("Exif:", exifDataRaw[i])
            return str(exifDataRaw[i].decode('utf_16_le'))
```

In this code I get the expected results.  `b'a\x00b\x00c\x00d\x00...`

So Image Exif data is little endian byte ordered.